# Is the data written to main memory when we write to memory-mapped I/O area?

Tags: memory, language-agnostic

I have a basic understanding of Memory-Mapped I/O (MMIO). Below is copied from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) page:

> Memory-mapped I/O uses the same address space to address both memory and I/O devices. The memory and registers of the I/O devices are mapped to (associated with) address values. So a memory address may refer to either a portion of physical RAM, or instead to memory and registers of the I/O device. Thus, the CPU instructions used to access the memory can also be used for accessing devices. Each I/O device monitors the CPU's address bus and responds to any CPU access of an address assigned to that device, connecting the data bus to the desired device's hardware register. To accommodate the I/O devices, areas of the addresses used by the CPU must be reserved for I/O and must not be available for normal physical memory.

My question is, suppose the address of the MMIO area is `addr`, if we issue a write to `addr`, will it be written to `addr` in main memory as well? Or only written to the memory within the I/O device?

My thought is as follows:

Since it is stated that "a memory address may refer to either a portion of physical RAM, or instead to memory and registers of the I/O device", the data will not be written to RAM, i.e. the data never goes to RAM, instead, it would be snooped by the memory controller of the I/O device, and written to the device memory.

If we issue a read from address `addr`, such read instruction will be captured by memory controller of I/O device and the data will be transferred from the device memory to the destination register in CPU. If we want the data to be in memory, then we need to issue another write, to another address `addr_new` (no overlap with `addr`).

May I know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: I am sure if I looked hard enough I could find computers that implement MMIO in different ways, think hobby computers. Don't take Wikipedia to be the gospel and always believe it. You at least get that by having asked this question. On the Wikipedia page it notes `This article needs additional citations for verification.` Many people don't take such messages to heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In memory-mapped I/O, there is no address that maps to both RAM and I/O registers -- it's one or the other.

It's really about the processor instruction set.

x86 processors have special instructions for reading and writing IO registers.

Memory-mapped I/O is the alternative.  You use the same instructions to use memory or I/O, and only the address you use determines which is which.

The simplest old-time implementation of memory-mapped I/O could just use one of the address lines to select either memory or I/O ports, requiring both of those to implement similar protocols.  That's not really practical today, though, because RAM is now complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that is the reason why physical memory is broken up into several pieces (see the figure on [this page](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/linuxsystems/belinuxsys-CHP-2-SECT-7.html)) - some reserved addresses are used specifically for memory-mapped IO.